# Footnote index does not start at zero

Tags: footnotes, indexing

In my document, I added a footnote. This is my first footnote, however, the index on the bottom of the page shows a `5` instead of a `1`.

My code for the footnote is as follows:

```
\footnote{TEXT}
```

Answering to [these suggestions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367920/wrong-index-for-footnote):

- There are no .aux files
- There is one footnote used later, which gives a `6`, indicating that it follows the count.
- I added a footnote before the current footnote. Now, the new footnote was indexed as `5` and the old one was indexed as `6`.
- There is no footnote in the floating area.
- No counter is manipulated manually.

What can I do, to change this into a `1`?

Comment: some code you have not shown has incremented the counter. It is impossible to debug this with the information given, please post a small  complete document that shows the problem.