# How do I put two footnotes in the caption of a float?

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

This question [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption) already has some suggestions on how to get a footnote in a caption. None seem really satisfactory because it seems hard to get the footnote text on the same page as the footnote mark. Anyway, I still want to do something more complicated: put *two* footnotes in one caption.

Is there a better way to do this and get the right numbering than to play around with the footnote counter manually? Obviously using `\footnotemark[]` is not an option because this *will* lead to wrong numbering sooner or later.

To demonstrate the default behaviour:

[image: caption]

[image: footnotes]

The code used was this:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption[Caption title in LOF]{This is a footnote in a caption\footnotemark{} and another one\footnotemark.}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{First footnote}
\footnotetext{Second footnote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A footnote to a caption is evil. Two is not even to be thinked of. ;-)

Comment: @egreg As long as it isn't so evil that I will get myself subjected to a targeted killing, I think I will go with what my text suggests ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LaTeX supports footnotes in floating objects by environment `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{Hello World}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\caption[Caption title in LOF]{%
  Caption title%
  \footnote{First footnote}%
  \footnote{Second footnote}%
}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That's actually a very good solution to the problem! Sorry for reacting so late.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this produces the footnotes just below the caption, instead of the bottom of the page (or at least in some document classes?).