# Footnotes inside captions using LyX

Tags: floats, captions

I finally found a way to insert a footnote inside a caption while using float:Table in LyX, [from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/footnotes-in-tables). You need to insert `\protect\footnotemark` in the caption and `\footnotetext{Text to footnote}` directly after the float.

See source:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
1 & 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
3 & 4\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\caption{This is the caption. \protect\footnotemark}


\end{table}

\footnotetext{Text to footnote}
```

Is there a more efficient way to include a footnote inside a caption when using LyX?

Comment: not a lyx user, so i don't know how this plays out, but in straight latex, a `\footnotemark` within a float and matching `\footnotetext` outside the float could end up on different pages.  rather counterproductive.

Comment: Yes indeed, that can be problematic in many cases.

Comment: I guess you could use a `minipage` (Insert --> Box --> Frameless) as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84331/586