# Using \footnotemark / \footnotetext trick for \footnote in \caption removes footnote number

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

I had the issue of having two footnotes appear in `\caption` in a `figure`-environment.  Fortunately, this answer ([Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption)) provided a solution.

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ReportMenu}
  \caption[The report submenu]{Each of the pre-defined reports appear as a menu item in the \textbf{Reporting} submenu.  Some installations have custom reports made special by Innovative for them, and only appears on installations that request it.  ``Report queue'' is the only item not a report,\footnotemark{} while ``Fleet statistics'' is a special report for fleet handling and only available for installations with the fleet module.  In this example, all available (at writing) custom reports appear, none of which have been translated into English as they are designed for Danish and Norwegian installations.  These custom reports will not appear on new installations.}
  \footnotetext{Since iv2.9e, another item for report scheduling has appeared underneath the report queue and is also not a report.}
  \label{fig:menu}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Which yields the following result:

[image: Picture of print result]

You'll notice that while the `5` for the inline note appears (this is correct at this point in the document), it does not appear the footnote itself.

How do I make the number (re-)appear on the footnote itself without having to manually force it?  I have a feeling I have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `\footnotetext{...}` after the `figure` environment.

[image]

Edit: I also study the case when `SCfigure` is used together with `minipage`.  Here `\parbox` is used instead of `minipage` though. Hope this will serve as a start.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{ReportMenu}
\parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{
 \caption[The report submenu]{Each of the pre-defined reports appear as a menu item in the \textbf{Reporting} submenu.  Some installations have custom reports made special by Innovative for them, and only appears on installations that request it.  ``Report queue'' is the only item not a report,\footnotemark{} while ``Fleet statistics'' is a special report for fleet handling and only available for installations with the fleet module.  In this example, all available (at writing) custom reports appear, none of which have been translated into English as they are designed for Danish and Norwegian installations.  These custom reports will not appear on new installations.}
 \label{fig:menu}}
%\end{minipage}
\end{SCfigure}
\footnotetext{Since iv2.9e, another item for report scheduling has appeared underneath the report queue and is also not a report.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With the possible (unavoidable) effect that the footnote can go in a different page than the figure.

Comment: @egreg -- Yes, indeed. For that case, \clearpage is what I would try, to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, but I have an unfortunate situation that my figure appears on a page of its own (which is also why this issue isn't such a big concern; as it is the only footnote on that entire page), so it is somewhat impractical to add the footnote to the page it is on.

Comment: In addition, when I use `minipage` I cannot use the `SCfigure` correctly, as the figure suddenly becomes rather thin.  My figure in question is rather tall, so it would be neat to move it to the right/left of a page.  But I consider that a different issue entirely.

Comment: @Svip -- please see my update.

Comment: Neat.  However, while I have decided to use your answer as the accepted one, I have decided to rewrite my text to avoid the footnote entirely.

Comment: Any other solutions than `\afterpage`, `\minipage`, `\clearpage` while having the footnote below the figure? The latter two work just fine, but without the footnote number. Else, can the number be brute forced somehow to be written there? `\footnotetext[number]{text}` does not work.

Comment: @Lucas Usually, i would use \footnotemark[number]{some text here} in conjunction with \footnotetext[]{}. If this does not answer you. Please ask a new question with a minimum example and link to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another most easy method would be to just write the required number inside of the footnote, together with the footnote text: something like `\footnotetext{$^{number}$ your usual footnote text.}` . The final number will be shifted from typical footnote numbers by a few millimetres. Definitely worth a thought if one does not want to deal with circumstantial other commands and  preamble definitions that might have an impact in other parts of the whole work...which - worst of all - might go undetected.