# Footnote in the caption

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

How to get a footnote into a caption of a figure? I have look at examples on the forum and I tried two:

```
\begin{figure}  
\centering
\label{position}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../img/f.png}
\caption[Caption for LOF]{Real caption\footnotemark{45454}}
\footnotetext{ffff}
\end{figure}
```

Here I do not know where to write a text of the caption, and it is not printed at the bottom of the page.

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../img/fig.png}
    \caption[Caption for LOF]%
      {Real caption\footnote{blah}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Here, there is a footnote at the bottom of the page but with a footmark a instead of number. I tried to set it by

```
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

but it does not help.

Comment: Use `\footnotemark` inside `caption` and `\footnotetext` in text... refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141600/using-footnotemark-footnotetext-trick-for-footnote-in-caption-removes-foot

Comment: `\footnotetext` should be placed outside of the `figure` environment, on the same page as the figure and before the next `\footnote`. See also: [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181/134144) Apart from that, please make sure the `\label` command is placed after the `\caption`, otherwise cross references don't return th eexpected numbers.

Comment: To conclude: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}  
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption[Caption for LOF]{Real caption\footnotemark{}}
\label{position}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{ffff}
\end{document}` should result in the expected output.

Comment: @leandriis And why on earth don't you post your answer and waste my and other folks time skipping through unanswered questions, which are answered, but in the comments section?

Comment: Thank you. Now, I have in capture three footnotemarks. They are denoted by 4, 5, 6 although  they are the first in the document. The footnotetexts are denoted all by six. What to do with that, please?