# Using biblatex-chicago \autocite inside \caption doesn't produce footnote

Tags: biblatex, captions, footnotes, citing, chicago-style

Using `biblatex-chicago` package to produce Notes & Bibliography style Chicago cite notation. For some reason the footnote mark appears but the footnote text fails to actually appear below in the footer:

**LaTeX Source:**

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,strict=true,threshold=1]{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

% ... removed irrelevant preamble

\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\begin{document}

% ... cited source 19 occurs before here

\section{American Intelligence and the Cuban Missile Crisis}

The lack of reliable and accurate intelligence by the Americans caused the Cuban Missile Crisis.
Perhaps if they anticipated or had definitive proof of offensive Soviet weapons they could have avoided the crisis.
There was a failure of SIGINT, low signal-to-noise HUMINT ratio, and perhaps common sense that contributed to the Cuban Missile Crisis.
That being said, the Director of Central Intelligence John McCone focused on the possibility of offensive missiles despite the lack of hard evidence.\textsuperscript{\textbf{[TODO: VIEW CITED SOURCE 12 ON PAGE 312]}}
It is interesting that McCone was an army of one among his colleagues.
No one seemed to understand the likelihood of the Soviets establishing MRBMs and IRBMs on America's doorstep.

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cuba}}
  \caption[Caption title in LOF]{Reconnaissance Objectives in Cuba\autocite[fig. 12.][]{Brugioni:1991aa}}
\end{figure}

% ... rest of LaTeX document
```

**Produces PDF:**

[image: Compiled result]

Why has it disappeared? I can muck about with `\footnotetext` and `\footnotemark` but it doesn't afford me the luxury of automated `Ibid. 1` and short-hand versions of the cited source if not the first occurrence in the paper.

Did I find a bug?

Comment: No, this isn't a bug. Footnotes in captions are [problematic](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ftncapt). You don't have the luxury of ibid tracking in floats anyway. The answer solves the problem. Otherwise one would normally use `\footnotemark` and `\footcitetext`, but for some reason chicago-notes style doesn't properly define the latter command. I would contact the biblatex-chicago author about that.

Answer (score 5):

Your example is neither complete nor minimal, so I couldn't compile it. But your issue should be resolved by adding `\usepackage{ftnxtra}`to your preamble.

For more suggestions have a look here: [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption)