# How to make a footnote on the figure or table caption

Tags: floats, footnotes, texmaker

Another problem has occurred. I just want to make a footnote on the caption of the figure, but it doesn't works. I can make a footnote just before `\end{figure}`, but it doesn't looks good. So can anyone of you please help me? I have tried a lot of different methods from the internet, but nothing has helped. So please help me.

Comment: Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption

Comment: Do you want the footnote text to show up at the bottom of the `figure` environment or at the bottom of the page that contains the `figure`?