# How to force footcites respectively footnotes in a caption of a figure on same page as the figure

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

Is there an elegant way to force a foot cite in a float object in case a figure to be on the same page as the float object(figure) without restrict the position of it, as mentioned here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10185 .

Elegant means that it is easily practicable on are large document, even if you make many changes anywhere in the document.

Comment: No. Floats shouldn't have footnotes at all.