# Footnote on the wrong page

Tags: footnotes

I have a page that have only a single figure (consisting of many images) on it and its caption. I want to put a footnote on the same page. I used some suggestions mentioned at SO like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67030/48093)  which gives the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics{foo}  ...
   \caption[Caption for LOF]{Real caption\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{blah blah blah}

\end{document}
```

**PROBLEM:** The footnote comes on the previous page that does not have figure and contains only text.

Comment: I get one page pdf file

Comment: latex doesn't support foonotes on float pages (from `[p]`) so you could try to force it to be on a text page by using `\begin{figure}[!h]` or definitely force it with `[H]` from float package) (not tested as you haven't provided a usable example...)

Comment: @touhami that's because the example posted isn't an example of the problem (complain to the OP:-)

Answer (score 2):

The posted example does not relate to the problem as the footnote comes on the same page as the figure.

I would guess you have

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[!ht]
   \centering
    \rule{1cm}{15cm}
   \caption[Caption for LOF]{Real caption\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{blah blah blah}

\end{document}
```

where the figure is on page 2 and the footnote on page 1.

If you uncomment `[!ht]` then it all comes on to one page.

Comment: I do have `[!ht]` after `\begin{figure}` in my figures but still the footnote is present on the above page which contains text.

Comment: @skm You have been on the site long enough to know: no proper example, no proper answer. Take the example in this answer and modify it to show the problem you have. Then fix your question so the example **is an example of the problem that you are asking about**

Comment: @skm you should not usually have `[!ht]` it is only for rare occasions where you need to force some behaviour (`!ht` disables float pages so makes it more likely that all floats go to the end of the document or `\clearpage`, which is probably what has happened in your case)