# Advanced table footnotes

Tags: tables, footnotes

I need to place footnotes on tables as in the following example, taken for Physical Review B:

[image]

Since Phys. Rev. B is written in LaTeX ([RevTeX](https://journals.aps.org/revtex)), I belive this should be possible with any class. I am using Classic Thesis with the ArsClassica package. I already achieved something very similar using a minipage:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
    \toprule
    & $a$ (\si{\angstrom}) & $c/a$ & $u$ & $B_0$ (\si{\giga\pascal}) & $B_0'$ & $E_g$ (\si{\electronvolt})\\
    \midrule
    GGA & \num{3.126} & \num{1.602} & \num{0.382} & \num{191} & \num{3.67} & \num{4.10}\\
    GGA\footnote{\cite{Stampfl1999}.} & \num{3.113} & \num{1.619} & \num{ 0.380} & \num{192} & \num{3.69} & \num{4.25}\\
    GGA\footnote{\cite{Zoroddu2001}.} & \num{3.110} & \num{1.606} & \num{0.382} & - & - & - \\
    Exp.\footnote{\cite{Stampfl1999}.} & \num{3.111} & \num{1.601} & \num{0.385} & \num{185}-\num{212} & \num{5.7}-\num{6.3}& \num{6.28} \\
    Exp.\footnote{\cite{Schulz1977}.} & \num{3.110} & \num{1.601} & \num{0.382} & \num{202} & - & - \\

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}

    \caption{Caption on top.}

\end{table}
```

This is the result:

[image]

However, here you can spot a big problem: since I used a minipage of width `\textwidth`, the footnotes are not aligned with the table (as in the example). It is possible to achieve this alignement? How?

---

Following Bernard's answer I used this:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Comparison of calculated binding energy and bond lengths for \ce{O2} and \ce{N2} with experimental and other theoretical values.}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
    \toprule
    & $E_b^\text{\ce{O2}}$ (\si{\electronvolt}) & $d_\text{\ce{O}-\ce{O}}$ (\si{\angstrom})& $E_b^\text{\ce{N2}}$ (\si{\electronvolt}) & $d_\text{\ce{N}-\ce{N}}$ (\si{\angstrom})\\
    \midrule
    GGA & \num{-5.855} & \num{1.215} & \num{-10.138} & \num{1.096} \\
    GGA\tnote{a}& - & - & \num{-9.867}& \num{1.105}\\
    GGA\tnote{b} & - & - & \num{-10.558} & \num{1.113}\\
    Exp.\tnote{c} & \num{-5.12} & \num{1.21} & - & - \\
    Exp.\tnote{a} & - & - & \num{-9.9}& \num{1.10}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[a] \cite{Stampfl1999}.
        \item[b] \cite{Zoroddu2001}.
        \item[c] \cite{Wang2008}.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

However, it seems to me that there is a problem with the caption, which is apparently constrained to the same length of the table:

[image]

Comment: See my answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99289#99289 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99293#99293 for two methods that might work in your case.

Comment: I think the second approach fits my needs, but how do I compute automatically the minipage width?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with `threeparttable`, which defines an eponymous environment, and a `tablenotes` environment. If you put the caption between`table` and `threeparttable` environments, the caption will have a width of `textwidth`; if you put it *inside* `threeparttable`, its width will be the actual width of the table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sf, width =\textwidth}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
    \caption{Caption on top. A long long long and very very silly caption . A long long long and very very silly caption.}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
      \toprule
                    & $a$ (\si{\angstrom}) & $c/a$ & $u$ & $B_0$ (\si{\giga\pascal}) & $B_0'$ & $E_g$ (\si{\electronvolt}) \\
      \midrule
      GGA & \num{3.126} & \num{1.602} & \num{0.382} & \num{191} & \num{3.67} & \num{4.10} \\
      GGA\tnote{a} & \num{3.113} & \num{1.619} & \num{ 0.380} & \num{192} & \num{3.69} & \num{4.25} \\
      GGA\tnote{b} & \num{3.110} & \num{1.606} & \num{0.382} & -- & -- & -- \\
      Exp.\tnote{c} & \num{3.111} & \num{1.601} & \num{0.385} & \num{185}-\num{212} & \num{5.7}-\num{6.3} & \num{6.28} \\
      Exp.\tnote{d} & \num{3.110} & \num{1.601} & \num{0.382} & \num{202} & -- & -- \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[a]\cite{Stampfl1999}
      \item[b]\cite{Zoroddu2001}
      \item[c]\cite{Stampfl1999}
      \item[d]\cite{Schulz1977}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \label{table2}
\end{table}



\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Caption on top. A long long long and very very silly caption . A long long long and very very silly caption.}

    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
      \toprule
                    & $a$ (\si{\angstrom}) & $c/a$ & $u$ & $B_0$ (\si{\giga\pascal}) & $B_0'$ & $E_g$ (\si{\electronvolt}) \\
      \midrule
      GGA & \num{3.126} & \num{1.602} & \num{0.382} & \num{191} & \num{3.67} & \num{4.10} \\
      GGA\tnote{a} & \num{3.113} & \num{1.619} & \num{ 0.380} & \num{192} & \num{3.69} & \num{4.25} \\
      GGA\tnote{b} & \num{3.110} & \num{1.606} & \num{0.382} & -- & -- & -- \\
      Exp.\tnote{c} & \num{3.111} & \num{1.601} & \num{0.385} & \num{185}-\num{212} & \num{5.7}-\num{6.3} & \num{6.28} \\
      Exp.\tnote{d} & \num{3.110} & \num{1.601} & \num{0.382} & \num{202} & -- & -- \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[a]\cite{Stampfl1999}
      \item[b]\cite{Zoroddu2001}
      \item[c]\cite{Stampfl1999}
      \item[d]\cite{Schulz1977}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution, but it seems to me there is a problem with long captions: the caption is (apparently) constrained to the same lenght of the table (I would like a caption of `\textwidth`) and the result is not appealing when the table is centered... Surely I am doing something wrong!

Comment: If you put the caption *inside* the `threeparttable` environment, it has the actual width of the table. If you put it between table and threeparttable, its width is `\textwidth`, unless you set it to another value, with `captionsetup{width=…}`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Now it looks exactly how I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The OP commented that he like my answer at [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99293#99293), though he/she was interested in automating the calculation of the `minipage` width.  Here I show how that might be done.  I place the `tabular` content into a `\def` for easy recall, and then place it in a temporary `\hbox`.  I then can use `\wd0` as the `minipage` width, and just recall the `tabular` content with the def'ed macro therein.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\begin{document}
This is an alternate way to do a footnote in a table, with the minipage
environment.
\begin{table}[ht]
  \def\tblcontent{\footnotesize\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    Title & Column 1 & Column 2\\
    \hline
    First Test & 1.234 & 5.389\footnote{\scriptsize This is the
     footnote text blah blah blah blahty blah}\\
    \hline
    Second Test & 3.894 & 1.586~~\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}}
  \setbox0=\hbox{\tblcontent}
  \centering
  \caption{Caption goes here}
  \begin{minipage}{\wd0}   % GUESS (OR CALCULATE) MINIPAGE WIDTH
    \renewcommand\footnoterule{}     % ELIMINATE LITTLE LINE SEPARATER
    \tblcontent
    \vspace{-2ex}                    % SHIFT FOOTNOTE UP
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but I find Bernard's solution slightly simpler! ; )