# tufte-latex: biblatex citations in captions

Tags: biblatex, margins, citing, tufte

How can biblatex citations used in captions of the tufte-book document class?

The following MWE does not work since the `\autocite` command in the image caption does not properly handled by tufte-book. I assume the marginnote needs to be queued somewhere in [tufte-common.def](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def).

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en-US
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,marginals=raggedright,nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=authortitle-icomp,    
    ]{biblatex}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    Citation in text.\autocite{westfahl:space}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \caption{Citation in caption.\autocite{westfahl:space}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that `biblatex`'s footnote detection does not work with the tufte classes (with the tufte classes one should probably consider a caption to be a footnote as well). So `\autocite` (which branches depending on whether we're in a footnote or not) goes miss, just use `\cite` and everything is tickety-boo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the Tufte classes are not too fond of you using a `\footnote` from within a `\caption`.
Since `biblatex` doesn't know we are using `\autocite` from within a `\caption` it defaults to `\footcite`; indeed since patching the `\footnote` command failed, `biblatex` can't even detect it is in a footnote and use `\parencite` there.

With

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname if@capstart\expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname iftrue\endcsname
    \global\let\@currentHref\hc@currentHref
  \else
    \hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}%
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{NR@gettitle}{%
    \def\@currentlabelname{#2}%
  }{%
    \NR@gettitle{#2}%
  }%
  \par\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}{%
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}%
  }%
  \begingroup
    \toggletrue{blx@footnote}%
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname if@capstart\expandafter\endcsname
                    \csname iftrue\endcsname
      \global\@capstartfalse
      %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces#3}%
      \noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces#3%
    \else
      %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{%
      \noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:
        \ignorespaces
        \ifHy@nesting
          \expandafter\hyper@@anchor\expandafter{\@currentHref}{#3}%
        \else
          \Hy@raisedlink{%
            \expandafter\hyper@@anchor\expandafter{%
              \@currentHref
            }{\relax}%
          }%
          #3%
        \fi
      %}%
    \fi
    \par
  \endgroup
}

\renewcommand\@footnotetext[2][0pt]{%
  \marginpar{%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize%
    \@tufte@margin@par% use parindent and parskip settings for marginal text
    \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark%
    }%
    \color@begingroup%
       \toggletrue{blx@footnote}%
       \@makefntext{%
         \ignorespaces#2%
       }%
    \color@endgroup%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
```

a bastardisation of `tufte-common.def`'s definitions, bits of what `hyperref.sty` does and patching done by `biblatex`, footnote detection will work and `\caption`s will be treated as if they were sidenotes by `biblatex`'s tracker.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,marginals=raggedright,nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=authortitle-icomp,    
    ]{biblatex}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname if@capstart\expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname iftrue\endcsname
    \global\let\@currentHref\hc@currentHref
  \else
    \hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}%
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{NR@gettitle}{%
    \def\@currentlabelname{#2}%
  }{%
    \NR@gettitle{#2}%
  }%
  \par\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}{%
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}%
  }%
  \begingroup
    \toggletrue{blx@footnote}%
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname if@capstart\expandafter\endcsname
                    \csname iftrue\endcsname
      \global\@capstartfalse
      %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces#3}%
      \noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces#3%
    \else
      %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{%
      \noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:
        \ignorespaces
        \ifHy@nesting
          \expandafter\hyper@@anchor\expandafter{\@currentHref}{#3}%
        \else
          \Hy@raisedlink{%
            \expandafter\hyper@@anchor\expandafter{%
              \@currentHref
            }{\relax}%
          }%
          #3%
        \fi
      %}%
    \fi
    \par
  \endgroup
}

\renewcommand\@footnotetext[2][0pt]{%
  \marginpar{%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize%
    \@tufte@margin@par% use parindent and parskip settings for marginal text
    \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark%
    }%
    \color@begingroup%
       \toggletrue{blx@footnote}%
       \@makefntext{%
         \ignorespaces#2%
       }%
    \color@endgroup%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Citation in text.\autocite{westfahl:space}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \caption{Citation in caption. \autocite{westfahl:space}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Dark magick indeed.

Comment: This worked for me.  However, I have an issue.  I am using style=verbose in biblatex and I am using the citecounter=true and citecounter=true options so that biblatex abbreviates in the margin of the tufte-book class subsequent citations of the same source.  However, using your solution, in the case where the citation of the source is not the first occurrence when it appears in the caption, biblatex is still treating it as the very first occurrance by not abbreviating it.  Is there a workaround or easy fix for this particular situation?

Comment: @Steven Citation tracking is disabled inside floats since they are "outside the normal flow of text". Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506161/35864 and linked issues help. If not, please open a new question with suitable example document.

Comment: @moewe Brilliant! That did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @moewe I have another issue that I have posted here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657138/tufte-latex-vertical-adjustment-of-biblatex-citations-in-captions   Perhaps you may be able to offer some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

I found a manual workaround based on [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption), but I would prefer an automated solution.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en-US
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,marginals=raggedright,nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=authortitle-icomp,    
    ]{biblatex}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\begin{document}
    Citation in text.\autocite{westfahl:space}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \caption{Citation in caption.\footnotemark}
    \end{figure}
    \footnotetext{\cite{westfahl:space}}
\end{document}
```