# How can I write explanations below tables?

Tags: tables

I have two tables and these tables are in one page. I wrote explanations about these. Although there a lot of space, explanations cannot be located below the tables. How can I fix these problems?

```
\begin{table} [!htp]

\caption{Enerji Eş Değerlikleri}
\label{tab:endeg}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
        Tür & Jul & BTU\\
        \hline\hline
        1 BTU &  $1054 $ J & -\\
        1 kWh & $3,6x10^6 $J & $3.412$ BTU\\
        1 kalori &  $4,184 $ J & $3,968x10^{-3}$ BTU \\
        1 eV & $1,602x10^{-19}$ J & $1,52x10^{-22}$ BTU\\
        \hline\
        \textbf{Kaynak:} (Crawley, 2013)
            \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Hello Hilal, and welcome to `tex.SE`. It is advised that you provide a MWE (minimal working example) of your code, so people can understand better what are you doing, and what you want to do!

Comment: Ok, you are right.

Comment: @Hilal are you familiar with LaTeX's concept of floating objects (the `table` environment is one of those)? I'm asking because your question suggests that you are not…

Comment: By the way, when posting code, copy your own and paste it into the question. We cannot copy from a screenshot ;-)

Comment: @clemens, Yes, you are right, i am new. The first time, i made tables. I am writing Phd thesis. I have read 'floting objects' but i think have seen yet. Am  i able to do something? I want explanations to be located below tables. And i dont want such spaces.

Comment: Thank you @Johannes_B, sorry, I dont know. I wanna to be seen codes and pdf together

Comment: @Hilal, load code, i.e. Minimal Working Example (MWE) and picture separately.  And MWE should be complete document with all necessary packages, which cause your problem. Instead real text you can use dummy text from `lipsum` package.

Comment: The floating means that the table is not typeset where you have it in the code but where LaTeX finds a suitable place (depending on the parameters). This is quite common in books and one of the reasons why a table has a caption and is referred to in the text via the table number (`\ref`).

Comment: If you mean footnotes as part of a table, then http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99293#99293 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99289#99289

Comment: if you are using the `table` environment, there's nothing to prevent you from putting a block of regular text within that environment following the `\end{tabular}` that closes the actual table.  you may have to add some manual space between table and text.

Comment: Thanks, you interest Dox, Johannes_B, Zarko, clemens, Steven B.Segletes and barbara beeton

Answer (score 0):

You can force LaTeX to put your tables at the position in the souce code by writing:

```
\usepackage{float}

\begin{table}[H]
   % Here comes your tabular
\end{table}
% Here comes your explanation
```

Comment: In the comments he states, that he is doing his PhD thesis. So I assume, he wants captions too.