# acmart: Footnotes in teaserfigure

Tags: footnotes, acm

I'm trying to add some URL footnotes to my `teaserfigure`. I'm trying the solution given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67030/5031) but I get odd results:

[image: Footnotemarks]
[image: Footnotes]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,sigconf]{acmart}
\begin{document}
\title{Here's a title}
\begin{teaserfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} \quad
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Image A from\protect\footnotemark\ and image B from\protect\footnotemark.}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\footnotetext{Source for image A}
\footnotetext{Source for image B}

\section{Introduction}
    Here's some text\footnote{And a footnote!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

With symbols in the footnotes

```
\documentclass[10pt,sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}
\title{Here's a title}
\begin{teaserfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} \quad
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Image A from\protect\footnotemark\ and image B from\protect\footnotemark.}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

{
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnotetext[1]{Source for image A}
\footnotetext[2]{Source for image B}
}
\section{Introduction}
    Here's some text\footnote{And a footnote!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Solution 2:**

Numbers everywhere

```
\documentclass[10pt,sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}
\title{Here's a title}
\begin{teaserfigure}
        \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} \quad
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Image A from\protect\footnotemark\ and image B from\protect\footnotemark.}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\footnotetext[1]{Source for image A}
\footnotetext[2]{Source for image B}
\addtocounter{footnote}{2}

\section{Introduction}
    Here's some text\footnote{And a footnote!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better! I'd actually rather have the footnotemarks be numbers starting right away.

Comment: @Dan Please see my second solution

Comment: Perfect! All it needs is `\scriptsize` in the `\renewcommand`: `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\scriptsize\arabic{footnote}}`