# Is there any easy way to add epigraphs to tables and graphs?

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I am a bit confused about how to add footnotes to tables. I have read some other similar questions but it is not working for me. I don't know what am doing wrong.

Here is a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}[H]
\centering
\captionof{table}{Convergencia PM6-cluster}\label{table:convergencia_cluster_PM6}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^\circ_{SS}$} & \textbf{$\Delta G^\circ_{Packmol}$} \\ \hline
5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
180 & -66.6 & -66.4 \\ \hline
250 & -66.3 & -67.0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] En la tabla se compara $\Delta G^0$ de dos métodos de solvatación (SS y Packmol) con hamiltoniano PM6. Los valores de $\Delta G^0$ se dan en Kcal/mol. La sigla SS significa Solvateshell.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}


But it produces a footnote with too big letters. So maybe I am using it wrong.
```

**edit**

[image]

Comment: Related answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99289#99289 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption/99293#99293

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*for legacy purpose:*

You can use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` for that. The latter outside of the `threeparttable`.

EDIT:

In `threeparttable` you have to specify the note's identifier with `\tnote` and use the identifier in the `tablenotes`-environment as optional argument to the `\item`. Note that the font size is not changed inside the `tablenotes`. For that you might issue a `\footnotesize` to reduce the font size. Also note, that you don't have to use the `tablenotes` environment nor the `\tnote` if you don't want to add footnote-like comments to your table, you can just put text there.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Convergencia PM6-cluster}\label{table:convergencia_cluster_PM6}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^\circ_{SS}$} & \textbf{$\Delta G^\circ_{Packmol}$} \\ \hline
5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
180 & -66.6 & -66.4 \\ \hline
250 & -66.3 & -67.0\tnote{a} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] En la tabla se compara $\Delta G^0$ de dos métodos de solvatación (SS y Packmol) con hamiltoniano PM6. Los valores de $\Delta G^0$ se dan en Kcal/mol. La sigla SS significa Solvateshell.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

A second try without tablenotes:

\begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{Foo}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    my & table\\
    being & nice
  \end{tabular}
  {\footnotesize Descriptive text}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

Note that you don't even need `threeparttable` for this. You could as well use a regular `table` environment containing a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
A third try without threeparttable:

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Foo}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    my & table\\
    being & nice
  \end{tabular}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \scriptsize
    long descriptive text. It is really long. Somebody should
    shorten it. Really, who reads all that stuff? Seems boring to me. You
    really should stop reading this.
  \end{minipage}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I refer to an epigraph (a short comment below the table) to the table, I don't know the word in english for that.

Comment: @HernanMiraola does my edit answer your question?

Comment: No. Tablenotes doesn't produce what I am looking for, the comment below the table has too big letters, i don't know why.

Comment: @HernanMiraola but that's what the `tablenotes` environment is there for. Your only problem is, that the text you added below the table is too big?

Comment: I have edited, look at the tablenote, it is huge.

Comment: @HernanMiraola just add a {\scriptsize Your text here} It reduces the size but if you don't like it you can add manually in a multicolumn row.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong about using `tablenote`. What I need is a short explanation of the table as an epigraph is in photos.