# Cite footnote not showing in figure environment

Tags: biblatex

For citing I'm using `biblatex` with the chicago style, and I want to use `\autocite` within the caption for a figure. However, even though the footnote number is shown within the caption, the corresponding footnote text doesn't appear on the same page nor on any page in the whole document.

I'm aware that you have to use `\protect` for this kind of matter, but it still doesn't seem to affect the result.

Here the simplified MWE of my LaTeX code segment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{some section}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{some subsection}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{...}
\caption[here some text]{here some more text.\protect\autocite[Vgl.][11]{dirac1981principles}}
\label{fig:figureone}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And here the according bibliography file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Book{dirac1981principles,
  title     = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  publisher = {Clarendon Press},
  year      = {1981},
  author    = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  series    = {International series of monographs on physics},
  isbn      = {9780198520115},
  keywords  = {physics},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

---

I already tried the solution mentioned in the thread [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption), and this is what I came up with:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{...}
    \caption[here some text]{here some more text.\protect\footnotemark}
    \label{fig:figureone}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{\cite[Vgl.][11]{dirac1981principles}}
```

But this is not what I first intended, because I want to change the cite style (by the use of `biblatex` arguments) dynamically, without any manual interference for each occurrence of cites within figure environments.

Comment: Hi! Could you please add a complete minimal working example? Ad hoc I would suggest that you put the figure environment into a minipage. The footnote however then appears at the bottom of said minipage.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT MWE added. To compensate the missing bibliography file, I changed the `autocite` command to `footnote`.

Comment: Check the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption . You can use `\footnotemark` in the caption, and then anywhere on the same page you add `\footnotetext{some explanation}`

Comment: Does footnotemark work with autocite?

Comment: To be fair it's actually not the same question as mentioned by you gentlemen. I adjusted the question to be more specific. Instead of `\footnote` I added `\autocite` again, this time together with an example bibliography file.