# Footnote in caption and in the same page of caption

Tags: captions, footnotes

I'm wondering if there is a way to write a footnote inside a caption and to stick the footnote in the same page of caption.

In my code I'm using footnotemark and footnotetext, but the footnote occurs two pages before the page in which there is the figure with caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{fig16}
    \caption[Caption for LOF]{Confronto con altri biosensori elettrochimici\footnotemark .}
    \end{figure}

    \footnotetext{Per [29], [39], [40], [2], [5], [41], [42], [15] si veda\cite{sun2016multi}.}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT: the figure is the following:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello @IAtExFaN, before the figure there are text.

Comment: your mwe is not compilable

Comment: @lAtExFaN you have to insert a figure. See the Herbert reply please: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption

Comment: you should provide a complete mwe. I cannot reproduce your mentioned result: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} %or load ’graphicx’ and ’blindtext’ manually
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
 \caption[Foo]{Bar\footnotemark .}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Foo Bar}
\Blindtext
\end{document}`

Comment: @lAtExFaN can you tell me how can I post more than 10 pages of code please? The only way to show the problem is to post the whole code.

Comment: there is a difference between a complete MWE and a complete document (for details see: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe)

Comment: Ok, i'm using clasicthesis template so the code is spread over several pages. @lAtExFaN if you want I can send you the file.

Comment: so I think, I cannot help you - sorry and good luck

Comment: if the footnote appears "two pages before" then I suppose that your image is too big. Then it will go to the end of the chapter. However, instead of `scale=0.3` use `width=\linewidth` _or_  `height=0.9\textheight` if the height has to be scaled.

Comment: Hello @Herbert, see the edit please.

Comment: Your table is too wide, use `width=\linewidth`

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem it is necessary to put the following code below the text which is in the same page of the figure (in this case below the sencente which finished with the word "luogo"):

```
\footnotetext{Per [29], [39], [40], [2], [5], [41], [42], [15] si veda\cite{sun2016multi}.}
```

[image]