# Footnote in Figure Caption for APA format appearing in different pages

Tags: apa-style

Looks like for majority of the Latex users the below solution worked but unfortunately not for me while trying to achieve the same result using APA format where figures come in succession after references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics{foo}  ...
   \caption[Caption for LOF]{Real caption\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{blah blah blah}

\end{document}
```

Wondering if anyone got it worked in APA format? Thanks for any help.

[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption)

Update: The following code works perfectly if the document has only one figure. However, the footnotes in subsequent figures appear on the same page of the first footnote, not in the same page of the subsequent figures.

```
\documentclass[man,12pt]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%footnote in caption
\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{fnpos}

    \begin{figure}[htb!]
       \includegraphics[width=17cm]{Figure1}
       \caption{\label{fig:exhibit1} Footnote 1\footnote{footnote 1}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```