# Footnote placed on the wrong page when figure placement is forced to page

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes, memoir, placeins

Whilst working with figures and footnotes, I noted a footnote placement issue. I have tried the different solutions listed in [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption), which does not work for me as I have the figures on a separate page, forced to a specific location in the document using floatbarrier (From testing the issue is stemming from the page placement). The footnote appears on the page before the figures or after. Any ideas how I make the footnote text appear on the same page of the figure?

Code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
% \usepackage{footmisc}

\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{fnpos}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext

some text

\section{Outline}
\blindtext

some text. some text\footnote{Foot note text 1}. More text
%\fnunderfloat
\makeFNbelow
\begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{minipage}{.7 \linewidth }
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{red.png}
        \caption[A caption 1]{A caption 1}
        \label{fig:figure1}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{green.png}          
        \caption[A caption 2]{A caption 2\footnotemark{}.}
        \label{fig:figure2}        
    \end{minipage} \footnotetext{reproduced from ... }   % is showed before figure page
\end{figure}


\FloatBarrier
%\footnotetext{reproduced from ... }   % is showed after figure page
%

\section{Approach}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Page one footnote]
[image: Page two footnote]

Comment: it is not an unreasonable requirement but latex does not support page footnotes on float pages. You could use a minipage inside the float and so get a minipage footnote under the caption.