# biblatex - footcite not working inside \begin{center}

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I'm struggling with `biblatex` to have footnote when the `\footcite` command is issued inside a `\begin{center} \end{center}` block.

The bibliography works fine, I have the reference number in the text but I'm unable to get the footnote at the same time.

I tried the command:

```
\footcite{ref1}
\footfullcite{ref1}
\footfullcitetext{ref1}
```

But it's not wokring.

This is what I have:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=numeric,
    citestyle=verbose,
    maxcitenames=50,
    maxbibnames=50,
    firstinits=false,
    sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio} 


\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{01_Content_Certif_X509}
\captionof{figure}{\emph{Génération et contenu d’un certificat X.509.}\footcite{dumas2013theorie}}
\end{center}
```

If I used the `\footcite` command outside the `\begin{center} \end{center}` block, it works fine.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please consider posting a fully compilable example document instead of several disconnected code snippets (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Without a proper MWE to test this my working assumption is that this is not due to the `center` environment, but rather due to the fact that footnotes don't work in captions. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181/35864.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@moewe, based on your link, this was the solution

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{01_Content_Certif_X509}\label{fig:1}
\captionof{figure}{\emph{Génération et contenu d’un certificat X.509.}{\protect\footnotemark}}
\end{center}
\footnotetext{\footcite{dumas2013theorie}
```

Comment: In this case it would be possible to reduce the `\footnotetext{\footcite{dumas2013theorie}}` to `\footcitetext{dumas2013theorie}`.