# Caption with footnote for side-by-side pictures

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes, minipage

I have two figures standing next to each other, each with their own captions. I want to have the image source in a footnote in each of their caption, and have the footnote displayed at the bottom of the page together with all the other footnotes. The method used in the example under does not achieve the expected/wanted result. Does anyone know if there's a way to achieve this?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{0.40\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{images/picture1.jpg}
        \caption[desc]{desc \footnote{source 1 url}}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.40\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{images/picture2.jpg}
        \caption[desc]{desc \footnote{source 2 url}}
    \end{minipage}  
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I think this can't effectively be done until the document is in final form and you know exactly where everything will be located.  At that point, this question may help: [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181).  You will have to tinker with the numbering of the `\figuretext` when more than one footnote is cited in a single `figure`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you liked the following solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}  % <---
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \footnotesize
    \color{black!80!white}   % <--- you can select black because
                }
\makeatother
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
                {source: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531908}}
    &   \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
                        {source: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531908}}  \\
\caption[left]{description of the left figure}
    &   \caption[right]{description of the right figure}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}       
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.40\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.40\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\textwidth}
            \captionof{subfigure}[desc]{desc \protect\footnotemark[1]}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\textwidth}
            \captionof{subfigure}[desc]{desc \protect\footnotemark[2]}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Figure caption}
    \end{figure}
    \footnotetext[1]{source 1 url}
    \footnotetext[2]{source 2 url}
\end{document}
```

PS: May be you should use the `\footnotetext` commands in another of the next pages...

Comment: Thank you alot for trying. This doesn't really achieve what I wanted, as this forces the footnote number to be a static variable, and will now have the same number as some other footnote. If I'm gonna use this solution I'm going to have to enter all future footnotes manually as well, seeing as I wan't all footnotes to be ordered and increment by 1. I think I'm just going to put the source in a parenthesis in the caption if there are no way of doing this.