# Using two \footnote in a figure's \caption

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

This question was asked for one footnote [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption). However, as far as I can see (and tried) the answers only work for one footnote. If I want to use two (quite common in our case, since we use it for publication references), the solutions do not count properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics{foo}  ...
   \caption[Caption for LOF]{Real\protect\footnotemark caption\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{blah blah blah}
\footnotetext{bloh bloh bloh}

\end{document}
```

Counting 'by hand' with the optional parameter is very painful, since insertion of a footnote on a preceding page will mix up the numbers. Is there a solution that counts properly? Maybe there is a better solution overall, the original question is almost 10 years old?

Answer (score 3):

Although resetting the footnote counter is a nuisance, this will work for multiple footnotes, at least when the figure and footnotes are on the same page and in the order shown with respect to other footnotes on the same page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

some text.\footnote{first footnote}

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \textbf{This is a figure.}
   \caption{Caption text\protect\footnotemark\ and more\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{second footnote}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{third footnote}

more text.\footnote{fourth footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 1):

Is this helps to you??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics{foo}  ...
   \caption[Caption for LOF]{Real\protect\ref{firstfootnote}
   caption\protect\ref{secondfootnote}}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext[5]{\label{firstfootnote}blah blah blah}
\footnotetext[6]{\label{secondfootnote}bloh bloh bloh}

\end{document}
```

I've used `\label` and `\ref` instead of `\footnotemark`...

Comment: This is already better, since I have to count only once. But I still have to manually number the \footnotetext, which might be become wrong if more \footnote are inserted.