# Footnote inside figure capture duplicated

Tags: floats, hyperref, footnotes

I have a hard time with footnotes...
I use the package `tablefootnotes` with a defined command `\spewnotes` to display multiple footnotes in a theorem, following [another post on this forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41173/165408).
However, sometimes a footnote placed inside a figure capture sometimes would skip a number
and the footnote text would appear twice, as you can see below with footnote 4 (or 3).

Can anybody explain to me why this is the case? Does it depend on the order of the imports, and if so, why? Thank you for helping me!

## Minimal working example

### Expected behaviour

Footnote 4 (rsp. 3) shouldn't be duplicated. Footnote 5 is displayed like I expect it.

### Observations

- Error goes away if I don't import `hyperref`
- Error goes away if caption has less than 55 characters
- Number of characters depends on imports (was at 60 in my full document)

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} % has to go after xcolor
\usepackage{thmtools}

\definecolor{colorLink}{RGB}{61, 145, 60}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter, thmbox=M]{theorem}


% tablefootnotes & \spewnotes are used for multiple footnotes within a theorem.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spewnotes}{%
\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
\global\let\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout\relax%
\gdef\tfn@fnt{0}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks,linkcolor=colorLink}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
    \begin{theorem}
        A theorem with\tablefootnote{A} two footnotes\tablefootnote{B}.
    \end{theorem}
    \spewnotes
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=gray!20] (0,0) ellipse (.2 and .1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[Fig1]{
                1aaa 1bbb 2aaa 2bbb 3aaa 3bbb
                4aaa 4bbb 5aaa 5bbb 6aaa 6\tablefootnote{Why does this appear twice?}.}
    \end{figure}
    \spewnotes
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=gray!20] (0,0) ellipse (.2 and .1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[Fig]{
                1aaa 1bbb 2aaa 2bbb 3aaa 3bbb
                4aaa 4bbb 5aaa 5bbb 6aaa \tablefootnote{It appears only once
                if the caption is short enough, $<56$ in this example
                (or $<61$ if I include my uni's .sty file)}.}
    \end{figure}
    \spewnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could always use \footnotemark (in the caption) and \footnotetext (outside the float/minipage).

Answer (score 0):

This has already been [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544485/165408) and as described there, the most concise solution is
to use

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
```

This has the disadvantage that single-line captions will not be centred but honestly that does not matter for me.