# How to guarantee the footnote is at the bottom when there is a table setting with [b]

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have a footnote in the text. However, there is a table with `\begin{table}[b]`. The table appears below the footnote now. Like this:

[image]

How can I make sure that the footnote is at the bottom instead of the table?

Comment: With `fnpos`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133295/11604

Comment: Do try `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`.