# How can I cite within a caption when using a footnote citation style (e.g., OSCOLA)?

Tags: captions, citing, footnotes, oscola

When citing a reference within a `caption` environment (and using a footnote referencing style, such as [`oscola`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola)), the superscript footnote number is added and the reference is added to the bibliography, but the footnote itself does not render.

How can I properly render a footnote reference within a `caption`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is inherent to `\footnote` declarations within `caption` environments. The solution for the referencing issue is the same as for general footnotes (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10185/201812) for more information).

Instead of this (assuming the use of `oscola` commands):

```latex
\begin{figure}
  \caption[]{Caption text.\autocite{ref}}
\end{figure}
```

do this:

```latex
\begin{figure}
  \caption[]{Caption text.\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{\cite{ref}.}
```