# Missing footnotes when using footcite command in the captions of figures with @artwork driver

Tags: biblatex, graphics, footnotes, biber, includegraphics

I have the problem that when I want to make a `\footcite` in the caption of a figure, that the footnote is missing and the hyperlink broken. The hyperlink links to the first page of the document. The `\footcite` command works fine in a normal sentence. I am using `latexmk` to compile my document.

Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[pdftex, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a test sentence which references an artwork. \footcite{artwork-test}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics{test.jpg}
    \caption{This is a test image which references an artwork. \footcite{artwork-test}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The .bib file looks like this

```
@artwork{artwork-test,
  title = {Hello this is a {test title}},
  author = {{John Doe}},
  date = {2018},
  url = {http://www.example.com},
  urldate = {2021-08-06}
}
```

Comment: All normal `\footnote`s in floats disappear. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181/35864. This is not specific to `\footcite`. I generally try to avoid footnotes in captions and instead go for parentheses. If you must have a footnote, you can try to go for the old `\footnotemark`-`\footnotetext` trick: `\caption[This is a test image which references an artwork]{This is a test image which references an artwork.\footnotemark}` and the *after* the figure `\footcitetext{sigfridsson}`.

Comment: @moewe Okay I plan on going with parentheses for images like you recommended. My approach would be to use \parencite in the caption and apa style in biblatex. But I still want the verbose style for the normal in-text \footcite commands. Is it possible to only have the apa style affec the \parencite command?

Comment: It is possible-ish with a bit of work. But I don't think that this is a particularly good approach. If you only ever use author-year/APA citation-style labels in captions and have full/verbose citations everywhere else that will just come across as odd.